# Where do I put shared constants in a C# application?

Tags: c#

I have some constant strings that are needed in multiple classes. How can I store and retrieve these constants in a way that meets these required criteria:

1. No duplication of information.
2. No function call to retrieve constants.
3. No namespace symbol prior to constant (IE: `Constant` not `Namespace.Constant`)

None of the solutions I've found so far meet every criteria:

1. Duplicate them in every class they are needed in (violates criteria #1).
2. Store them in a separate static class that is referenced wherever needed (a bit like a C-style header file, violates criteria #3).
3. Put them in one of the classes where they are used and reference that class when they are needed elsewhere (this is seems like a bad idea because it could create circular references, and it violates criteria #3).
4. Put them in app.config and retrieve them whenever they are needed (This seems to break style conventions since non-configuration data is stored in a config file, and a change to the config file could break application logic. It also violates criteria #2).

Is there a solution in C# that meets every criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use option #2 often, because #1 is rife with risk of different values, and #3 breaks normally-sought class encapsulation.  If you must have globals. have one Single Source of Truth for them.

You can make the code somewhat cleaner with a `using` alias:

```
 using static namespace.StaticClassName;
```

Comment: Option #2 requires extraneous code wherever the constants are needed (`StaticClass.Constant` instead of just `Constant`). Is there a way around that?

Comment: @slbelden if you are using C# 6 (VS 2014 or newer) then yes. You can do `using static YourNamespace.StaticClass;` at the top of your file. it then makes all of the static members of `StaticClass` act as if they are in scope for the file.

Comment: Welcome to OOP ;) Of course there is a way around use both. In #1 assign the value of #2. I also prefer #2, but it is realy primarly opinion based...

Comment: @slbelden: "Option #2 requires extraneous code wherever the constants are needed" - Only for small projects. I have found that in larger projects, I like to sort my constants into several such static classes by topic, anyway.

Comment: @slbelden Thanks,  [Take a peek at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net has [Module Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/module-statement) that can be used for global variables that can be accessed without using the name of the module, but C# doesn't have anything like that.

In C# I use #2, but with `const`. That way the value is shown when you hover it in Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: OP's question was about C#.